# docker env variable logging to same session

Tags: docker

Here is my docker-compose file that creates a zookeeper and kafka.

For my kafka I set 2 env variables as given below.

Now, I hit docker-compose up and it creates the 2 containers.

How can I login to the same session where the env variables is set. When I do docker exec -it it takes me to a running container but don't see the env variable set. How can I login to the same session where the env variable is set.

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.1.162

      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

> When I do docker exec -it it takes me to a running container but don't see the env variable set.

Are they set? Try

```
environment:
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.1.162
```

to

```
environment:
  KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=192.168.1.162
```

I can't find any mention of assigning variables with a colon in a docker compose: https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/#the-env-file